# Check a [String: AnyObject] dictionary for a list of keys with values of specific types?

Tags: swift, dictionary, key-value-coding

One of my web services returns a dictionary of [String: AnyObject]. I'm trying to write a wrapper that will validate that the dictionary contains the expected keys and value types. How can I achieve this?

Example

```
let val1 = "A String"
let val2 = 0
let val3 = 3.14
let dict = ["key1" : val1 as AnyObject,
            "key2" : val2 as AnyObject,
            "key3" : val3 as AnyObject]

// Search for "key1" : String and "key2" : Int
```

Example 2

Some people are asking how I'm getting the dictionary.

```
Alamofire.request(address, withMethod: .post, parameters: params, encoding: .url, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            guard let value = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] else
            {
                print("Malformed data received from the service")
                return
            }
```

Comment: does it return a dictionary or a json?

Comment: JSON, but I convert it to a dictionary of type Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

Comment: if it returns json, then you can use swiftyjson to parse that json response

Comment: Okay. That's not my question.

Comment: @GoldenJoe Can you show your api calling code?

Comment: It's just boilerplate Alamofire stuff. It parses the JSON for me and gives me a dictionary. This isn't a JSON question, I just wanted to give the problem some context.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is via generics and exceptions:

```
enum ExtractErrors: ErrorType {
    case KeyNotFound, TypeMismatch
}

extension Dictionary {
    func extract<T>(key: Key) throws -> T {
        guard let value = self[key] else { throw ExtractErrors.KeyNotFound }
        guard let result = value as? T else { throw ExtractErrors.TypeMismatch }
        return result
    }
}

// this will throw an exception if an Int is not present at the "id" key
let id: Int = try dict["id"]
```

Building up a model from that JSON with this approach is easy:

```
struct Person {
    let id: Int
    let name: String

    static func fromDict(dict: [String:AnyObject]) -> Person? {
        do {
            return Person(id: try dict.extract("id"),
                          name: try dict.extract("name"))
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

If the dictionary is invalid, then the function returns nil.

You can go further and use associated values on the enum to find out which key is problematic:

```
enum ExtractErrors<Key>: ErrorType {
    case KeyNotFound(key: Key)
    case TypeMismatch(key: Key, expected: String, received: String)
}

extension Dictionary {
    func  extract<T>(key: Key) throws -> T {
        guard let value = self[key] else { throw ExtractErrors.KeyNotFound(key: key) }
        guard let result = value as? T else { throw ExtractErrors.TypeMismatch(key: key, expected: "\(T.self)", received: "\(value.dynamicType)") }
        return result
    }
}

let d = ["id":"aStringNotANumber","name":"John"]
do {
    let id: Int = try d.extract("name")
} catch let err {
    print("Invalid dictionary: \(err)")
}
```

The above prints

> Invalid dictionary: TypeMismatch("name", "Int", "String")